# std::sort with personal class returns segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have a small problem with `std::sort`.

When I try to sort an allocated array of objects using the override of the "<" function with `std::sort`, I get a segmentation fault.

You can see the problem here below in a toy example: In my `class point`, I allocate an array of personal objects `key` (especially I allocate the memory for an array `v`). Its elements are initialized, and then I try to sort this array.

With small sizes (for the array `v` and the array to sort), I get no error, and valgrind returns none.
For big sizes, I get a segmentation fault, and valgrind outputs a lot of errors I don't understand.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

```cpp
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
class key
{
    public :
        int size;
        double *v, f;

        key() {}
        key(const key & k)
        {
            size = k.size;
            f = k.f;
            v = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                v[i]=k.v[i];
        }
        ~key()
        {
            free(v);
        }
        bool operator<(const key& other) const
        {
            return f<other.f;
        }
        void init(int s)
        {
            size = s;
            v    = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                v[i]=((double)rand()/(RAND_MAX));
        }
};
class point
{
    public :
        key *k;

        point() {}
        point(int param1, int param2)
        {
            k = (key*)malloc(param1*sizeof(key));
            for(int i=0;i<param1;i++)
            {
                k[i].init(param2);
                k[i].f=param1-i;
            }
            std::sort(k,k+param1);
            free(k);
        }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    point p(100,21200); // segmentation fault!
    //point p(10,2);    // no segmentation fault!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `malloc`?  Why not use `std::vector<double>`?  Just that one change alone would probably fix the problem.  Right now, your classes are not safely copyable due to a lack of copy / assignment operator to handle that `double *` member.  Getting rid of it and replacing it with `std::vector` corrects all of these problem automatically.

Comment: It goes even worse than that; there's a `malloc` for an array of `key`s which is not POD. That's not going to end well.

Comment: What are the errors valgrind outputs that you don't understand?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Worse even, constructing a key and destroying it without calling `init` will pass an uninitialized pointer to `free`, causing even more UB.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Indeed, if I use vectors, it will work. But I want to know why there is a segmentation fault in this case.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Yes, but it is never the case in my code, no?

Comment: @user85022 It's probably the case in `sort`'s code.

Comment: @user85022 Where is the assignment operator?  Why are you not initializing your `key` and `point` members on construction?   I can easily crash your code by creating an array of key objects and calling sort on them, all due to uninitialized members.  Also `std::sort` is going to make copies, and you class is not safely copyable.

Comment: @user85022 *Indeed, if I use vectors, it will work* -- Now figure out why it is *Indeed*.  The reason for the *Indeed* is exactly why your class bombs out.  A `vector` has correct copy semantics, your class doesn't.  So the trick is to have a class that has correct copy semantics, and that is done by writing user-defined (and correct) copy assignment operators and destructor if you're managing dynamically allocated memory (which is exactly what `vector` has internally).

Comment: @user85022 Bad code is bad code, even if you happen to currently use it in a way that doesn't trigger one particular problem. A constructor that doesn't put the object in a destructable state is a big no-no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your classes need a copy constructor (or a move constructor) and a custom assignment operator because they manage raw pointers (resources). Otherwise when `std::sort` performs assignments of your `point` or `key` objects, the corresponding objects' data is not deep copied, but only the pointers are copied. Your destructor then ends up freeing the memory for pointers that point to the same memory address, which results in undefined behaviour (you'll often get a segfault on Linux/Unix). Also, remove those `malloc/free`s and replace them by `new[]/delete[]`. Or better, use standard containers like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Note that some compilers can catch this issues at compile time. For example, gcc with `-Weffc++` spits out an warning:

> **warning**: `struct Foo` has pointer data members [-Weffc++]
>   but does not override `Foo(const Foo&)`

Comment: The class needs a copy constructor because it manages a resource, not because it contains raw pointers.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, of course, the wording was a bit sloppy, edited.

Comment: @vsoftco I added a copy constructor (see edits), but it's not working.

Comment: @user85022 Both classes need copy constructors. Also, see the comments below your question, now your default ctor of `key` doesn't initialize the pointer. That default ctor will be called internally by `std::sort` when constructing temporary objects. Make it `nullptr` otherwise the destructor attempts to delete non-initialized pointers, which is again undefined behaviour. Finally, get rid of those `malloc` and `free` and replace them by `new/delete[]`. BTW, it's a good rule of thumb to initialize everything in your default constructor.

Comment: @vsoftco Ok! Now I see, the default constructor is called inside std::sort. Thank you very much, that is what I was looking for!